# Use `cut` to extract a list from /etc/passwd

Tags: bash, text-processing, cut

How could I use the `cut` command to extract a list of usernames and login shells from the `/etc/passwd` file, where the resulting usernames and login shells are separated by a single space?

Sort the resulting list in ascending alphabetical order, using the login shell as the primary key, and the username as a secondary key. Store the result in the newly created file `~/usershells.txt`.

This is the command I attempted:

```
cut -d /etc/passwd -k7 -k1 | sort > ~/usershells.txt
```

Comment: this is what I inputted cut -d /etc/passwd -k7 -k1 | sort > ~/usershells.txt that was my input.

Comment: If you run the cut command, you will be told what is wrong. first `-d` needs a parameter in this case `:`, then there is no option `-k`, so we look in the manual and find that we need `-f`, then we find that we can only specify `-f` once, so we need `-f7,1`. So the morel is “sometimes the error message is useful: always read the error message” (-1)

Comment: Is this homework? if so tag it as such. We will help you learn, but it is not good if we do your homework for you. You will not learn.

Answer (score 3):

```
cut -f 1,7 -d: /etc/passwd | tr ":" " " | sort -k 2,2d -k 1,1d
```

This will sort on field 2 as primary key and on field 1 as secondary, using dictionary sort.

If you wish to switch the columns, simply use awk:

```
cut -f 1,7 -d: /etc/passwd | tr ":" " " | sort -k 2,2d -k 1,1d | awk '{print $2,$1}'
```

which suggests using awk to get:

```
awk -F ":" '{print $7,$1}' /etc/passwd | sort -k 2,2d -k 1,1d
```

Which is not using cut, but not sure how hard a requirement using cut is for you.

If you don't want to use awk at all, you can still switch the columns order.
Here is one example using while loop and read:

```
cut -f 1,7 -d: /etc/passwd | tr ":" " " | sort -k 2,2d -k 1,1d | while read -r c1 c2;do echo "$c2 $c1";done
```

Another option using "cut & paste":

```
paste <(cut -f7 -d: /etc/passwd) <(cut -f1 -d: /etc/passwd) | sort -k 2,2d -k 1,1d
```

or, if the single space is hard requirement:

```
paste -d " " <(cut -f7 -d: /etc/passwd) <(cut -f1 -d: /etc/passwd) | sort -k 2,2d -k 1,1d
```

simply redirect any of the options listed to a file by using > ~/usershells.txt

of course you could still use cut'n'paste to keep the original order and still sort on the shells:

```
paste -d " " <(cut -f1 -d: /etc/passwd) <(cut -f7 -d: /etc/passwd) | sort -k 2,2d -k 1,1d > ~/usershells.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

For sorting you don't have to use `cut`, only use `sort` with *piping*:

```
sort -t " " -k 7 /etc/password |  sort -t " " -k 1
```

The piping order insures that login shell will used as the primary key, and the username as a secondary key.

`-t " "` will use `space` as a separator.

To only show the two columns use `cut` (after sorting):

```
sort -t " " -k 7 /etc/password |  sort -t " " -k 1 | cut -f 1,7 -d:
```

and finally you can save the output in the file `usershells.txt`:

```
sort -t " " -k 7 /etc/password |  sort -t " " -k 1 | cut -f 1,7 -d: > ~/usershells.txt
```

and if your default separator is `:` you can use `tr`as [Dani_l](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/144714/1174) mentions:

```
tr ":" " " /etc/password |  sort -t " " -k 7| sort -t " " -k 1 | cut -f 1,7 -d: > ~/usershells.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

The paramater f allows you to select the field, and d sets what the separating character is

```
 cut -f 1,7 -d: /etc/passwd
```

Comment: Welcome to the site. Could you please try and address the rest of the Q as well?

Answer (score 0):

```
cut -f 1,7 -d: /etc/passwd | tr ":" " " | sort > ~/usershells.txt
```